# Breadcrumb - How to change the element according to the page?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a forum software and I would like when my breadcrumb links, change depending on what I clicked:

[image: First breadcrumb]

And:

[image: Second breadcrumb]

Here is how my files are coordinated:

[image: Folder structure]

> header.php, index.php, members.php, css/style.css

I would like that the element automatically changes according to the clicked page.

header.php code:

```
<div id="top_bar">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="top_bar_links">
            <ul>
            <?php
            $full_name = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
            $name_array = explode("/",$full_name);
            $count = count($name_array);
            $page_name = $name_array[$count-1];
            ?>
            <li>
                <a class="<?php echo ($page_name=="index.php")?"active":"";?>" href="index.php">Forums</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="<?php echo ($page_name=="members.php")?"active":"";?>" href="members.php">Members</a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1 id="logo">
            <a href="index.php">NextGenFocus</a>
        </h1>
        <div id="user_links">
            <ul>
                <li id="sign_up">
                    <a href="sign_up.php">Sign Up</a>
                </li>
                <li id="sign_in">
                    <a href="sign_in.php">Sign In</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="breadcrumb_top">
            <div class="breadcrumb_links">
                <ul>
                    <li class="forums">
                        <a href="index.php">Forums</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

index.php and members.php code:

```
<?php
include "header.php";
?>
```

style.css code:

```
/* CORE */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 18px;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 17px;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 15px;
}

h6 {
    font-size: 13px;
}

    body {
        background-color: #e6e9ed;
        color: #000;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        margin: 0;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
    }

    .wrapper {
        width: 980px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    a {
        color: #4d7799;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    p {
        margin: 0;
    }

    /* TOP BAR */
    #top_bar {
        background-color: #262d35;
        height: 55px;
    }

    #top_bar_links ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #top_bar_links a {
        color: #fff;
        opacity: 0.6;
        float: left;
        display: block;
        line-height: 55px;
        padding: 0 25px;
    }

    #top_bar_links a:hover {
        background-color: #000;
        opacity: inherit;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #top_bar_links a.active {
        background-color: #000;
        opacity: inherit;
    }

    #top_bar_links a:hover {
        background-color: #000;
        opacity: inherit;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    /* HEADER */
    #header {
        background-color: #3d5e78;
        height: 115px;
        margin-bottom: -25px;
    }

    #logo {
        float: left;
    }

    #logo a {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 25px;
        line-height: 90px;
    }

    #logo a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #user_links li {
        float: right;
    }

    #user_links ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #user_links a {
        color: #fff;
        line-height: 90px;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }

    /* CONTAINER */
    #container {
        background-color: #fff;
        box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0px 1px 7px;
        padding: 15px;
    }

    #breadcrumb_top {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        height: 45px;
        margin: -15px -15px 15px -15px;
    }

    #breadcrumb_bottom {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        height: 45px;
        margin: 0 -15px -15px -15px;
    }

    .breadcrumb_links ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .breadcrumb_links li {
        float: left;
    }

    .breadcrumb_links a {
        color: #000;
        line-height: 45px;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }

    .separator {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
```

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow!** Please post your code here rather than links to, so that people can quickly help you diagnose and fix your problems.

Comment: These pictures are absolutely useless... Post some code ^_^.

Comment: How do you want them to change? By the way, write @Shahar if you want me to be notified of your comment.

Comment: @Shahar, can you help me? I put my codes...

Comment: "the element automatically changes according to the clicked page" don't you have that in the PHP file? What do you mean by that?

Comment: Take an example here: http://xenforo.com/community/ When I go to Members, "Members is displayed on the breadcrumb, etc.

Comment: When I see your script, then you should remap the for the breadcrumb link. Such as : $breadcrumb = array("Home", "Member");

Then write it to : Home > Member

Comment: Can you restructure my code, please?

Comment: I'd advise you to delete your message asking for your code to be restructured - that sounds like you want someone to do all the work for you. Often such requests are met with downvotes or closure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to put something dynamic where you presently have 'Forums'. You have your pagename (members.php) in the variable `$page_name`, so try this:

```
<?php echo ucfirst(str_replace('.php', '', $page_name)) ?>
```

That will remove the ".php" from the string (so it turns into "members") and then upper-case the first letter (so it turns into "Members"). Don't be afraid to try out some other string operations if you need to adjust it further!

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help. I use this code, now: http://prntscr.com/48ie3e http://prntscr.com/48ie9r